# Serialize form data into JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to serialize a form data into a JSON Object, but I get stuck when I need to create the *carts* object.

What I want to achieve after getting all the data in the form is an Object like the snippet below. How can I do this?

So you can see and test the full code here http://jsbin.com/OyAzAZA/3/

```js
{
  "client_id": 1,
  "carts": [
    {
      "cart_id": 1,
      "items": [
        {
          "code": "01",
          "descrption": "text 1"
        },
        {
          "code": "02",
          "descrption": "text 2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cart_id": 2,
      "items": [
        {
          "code": "03",
          "descrption": "text 3"
        },
        {
          "code": "04",
          "descrption": "text 4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to create the *carts* Object and go ahead. I've created the `data = {}` and `data.client_id = clientId` and now inside the two `$.each()` I've no idea on how to create the remaining Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that gets you the specified JSON:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on('click', 'button', function() {
        var clientId = $('form').find('input[name="client_id"]').val(),
        $tables = $('form').find('table'),
        data = {};

        data.client_id = clientId;
        data.carts = [];

        $.each($tables, function(i, v) {
            var cart = {};
            cart.cart_id = $(v).attr('id');
            cart.items = [];
                $rows = $(v).find('tr');

            $.each($rows, function(i, v) {
              var item = {};
                item.code = $(v).find('input[name="code"]').val();
                    item.description = $(v).find('input[name="description"]').val();
              cart.items.push(item);
            });
          data.carts.push(cart);
        });
    console.log(data);
});
});
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot because reading your code I've learned something more about JavaScript Object.